# 'Let not + noun/pronoun' vs 'Let + noun/pronoun + not'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, imperative-sentences, let

I know that the sentence *"Do not let him go"* sounds okay. Now-a-days the phrase *"Let not"* is, however, old-fashioned (*"Let me not to the marriage of true minds*" sonnet 116, Shakespeare)but grammatical.

*Let not him go.*
*Let not the boy go.*
*Let him not go.*
*Let the boy not go.*

Are all these sentences grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

The first two sentences:

> Let not him go.
>
> &
>
> Let not the boy go.

Wouldn't work, it is a verb + adverb, which isn't proper English grammar in this case.

Only verb + pronoun would work in this case, like:

> Let him not go.
>
> &
>
> Let the boy not go.

But usually, "let" is used that you accept and permit somebody to do something. Like:

> Let him go.
>
> &
>
> Let the boy go.

So in this case, I'd prefer:

> Don't let him go.
>
> &
>
> Don't let the boy go.

Comment: But I have seen the both usages : *'Let him not...'* or *'Let not him...'*; of course, both of these are *archaic*.

Comment: @SandipKumarMandal "Let not him" isn't proper grammar. I don't know where you saw that.